# Where are the implementations of math_ops trigonometric functions in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am looking for implementation of `math_ops.sin` and `math_ops.cos` functions in TensorFlow. Do they use numpy internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're defined in the C++ interface and internally they use the Eigen or CUDA libraries (it depends if CUDA is enabled or not).

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/79e65acb81f750ffa88b366c566646d48d16c574/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_cos.cc) you can see where the cosine function is defined.

In [math_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fa31914440571746c6d962de2a4fb4950576f367/tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc#L447), instead, you can see where the "Cos" function is registered. Once registered it can be imported from python importing it from the `math_ops` module.

Comment: Thanks @nessuno. The issue I am facing is `cos(45 Deg)` is correct while `sin(45 Deg)` is calculated wrongly on my platform in TensorFlow with CPU! I verified that with numpy, however, the values match(np.sin(45)=np.cos(45)). So with CPU it should use Eigen for the calculation correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. However when the results are random usually there are memory issues (you're going out of memory)

Comment: Doesn't seem like memory issue as below numbers are consistent every time :
`(Pdb) math_ops.cos(0.78539819).eval()   = 
0.70710677    ; 

(Pdb) math_ops.sin(0.78539819).eval()   = 
0.70710683 .`  
the difference even though very small, is critical, as it is causing test failures.

Comment: Wait, this is because of the float representation. You should NEVER check for equality when using float values, you have to check for closeness. Look at np.isclose: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html

Comment: Sorry if above `=` statement confused you. Added the equal sign just to represent the values in the comment as it did not go to the next line. The `math_ops.sin` needs to be precisely the same as `math_ops.cos` for the [test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.2.1/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/kernel_tests/image_ops_test.py#L48) to pass. More details in [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14017) raised with TensorFlow. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about `tf.cos` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cos) and `tf.sin` ?

Comment: Not really. I am looking for definitions of the math_ops.sin used [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.2.1/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/ops/image_ops.py#L115).